What is the purpose of `aws:rds:dbinstance` environment option for AWS Elastic Beanstalk
I am confused as to what the purpose of the aws:rds:dbinstance environment option the can be specified as part of the .ebextensions configuration file.
As far as the documentation goes, it is to "Configure an attached Amazon RDS DB instance". This doesn't seem to be the case however, as I have created an attached RDS using the EB CLI which is covered in this SO answer. I understand that the .ebextensions configuration file is evaulated per deployment (as answered here). However, when I run eb deploy ensuring that I am using the corrrect environment with eb use my-env, using the configuration files below, the attached database created with Elastic Beanstalk hasn't had any configuration change?
If you can't create the RDS instance with the configuration, and it doesn't seem to update once you've created it using the EB cli then what is the point of it? How can you use it to programatically configure databases, what am I missing? Why does it not seem to work?
Edit: I believe it could be used to configure the desired instance when using eb create -db however those configurations still do not get picked up?
.ebextensions/01_conf.config

option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:command:
    DeploymentPolicy: AllAtOnce
  aws:rds:dbinstance:
    DBAllocatedStorage: 5
    DBEngine: postgres
    DBEngineVersion: 16.2
    DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro

After running eb deploy


You need to ensure you've committed any changes before running eb create or eb deploy to alter the configuration. I found this really unclear from all the documentation. It is because EB uses the package committed to take the configuration/files, rather than looking locally. I found it out through this video.
